# Merging an array of objects and also merging the arrays inside the objects with the same key

Tags: javascript

So I have an array of objects called mergeItems that has a value of what you see below

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
city: [Array(13)]
miles: [Array(13)]
phone: [Array(13)]
photos: [Array(13)]
prices: [Array(13)]
state: [Array(13)]
titles: [Array(13)]
urls: [Array(13)]
who: [Array(13)]
__proto__: Object
1: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
2: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
3: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
4: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
5: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
6: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
7:
city: [Array(0)]
miles: [Array(0)]
phone: [Array(0)]
photos: [Array(0)]
prices: [Array(0)]
state: [Array(0)]
titles: [Array(0)]
urls: [Array(0)]
who: [Array(0)]
__proto__: Object
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
```

It has objects inside the array and then each object has the same keys inside of them. I am trying to merge all 7 arrays together, and then also merge all the city, miles, etc keys and the arrays inside of them.

I tried doing

```
let newData = mergeItems.join();
setState({mainItems: newData});
```

but since that only seems to merge the arrays that does me no good. Was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction on how this could be handled. Thanks so much =]

My current value of mergeItems is:

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
1: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
2: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
3: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
4: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
5: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
6: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
7: {urls: Array(1), titles: Array(1), miles: Array(1), prices: Array(1), photos: Array(1), …}
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
```

My desired output would look like this

```
{urls: Array(7), titles: Array(7), miles: Array(7), prices: Array(7), photos: Array(7), …}
city: (7) [Array(120), Array(0), Array(18), Array(57), Array(1), Array(0), Array(13)]
miles: (7) [Array(120), Array(0), Array(18), Array(57), Array(1), Array(0), Array(13)]
phone: (7) [Array(120), Array(0), Array(18), Array(57), Array(1), Array(0), Array(13)]
photos: (7) [Array(120), Array(0), Array(18), Array(57), Array(1), Array(0), Array(13)]
prices: (7) [Array(120), Array(0), Array(18), Array(57), Array(1), Array(0), Array(13)]
state: (7) [Array(120), Array(0), Array(18), Array(57), Array(1), Array(0), Array(13)]
titles: (7) [Array(120), Array(0), Array(18), Array(57), Array(1), Array(0), Array(13)]
urls: (7) [Array(120), Array(0), Array(18), Array(57), Array(1), Array(0), Array(13)]
who: (7) [Array(120), Array(0), Array(18), Array(57), Array(1), Array(0), Array(13)]
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Can you post the desired output and a sample input?

Comment: Added my desired output and the input is the value I posted before.

Comment: Added another one thats is easier on the eyes lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to end up with an object whose values are arrays of arrays (instead of one combined array for each key). In that case, you can use this:

```js
const mergeItems = [
    { urls: [1, 2, 3], titles: ['a', 'b', 'c'] },
    { urls: [4, 5, 6], titles: ['d', 'e', 'f'] }
];

let newData = {};
Object.keys(mergeItems[0]).forEach(key => {
    newData[key] = mergeItems.map(item => item[key])
});
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: So when I use this I get the output almost correct but the arrays inside the objects do not have the right amount of values

Comment: {urls: Array(7), titles: Array(7), miles: Array(7), prices: Array(7), photos: Array(7), …}
city: (7) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
miles: (7) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
phone: (7) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
photos: (7) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
prices: (7) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]

Comment: state: (7) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
titles: (7) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
urls: (7) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
who: (7) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
__proto__: Object

Comment: for example there, as you can see, all the arrays are at 1 instead of 120 like they should be

Comment: I can't tell why that would be the case without seeing your actual source data. You can run the snippet above and see that you get an array of `Array(3)` for each key.

Comment: So inside of the object state for example, there are also 8 arrays, and inside those 8 arrays, are even more arrays that need to be merged LOL.

Comment: Ok then try using `flatMap` instead of `map`.

Comment: Thanks so much man I know this was a tricky question. I really do appreciate your time this is going to make a huge difference in the way I was handling this part of my project.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, fundamentally you have:

```
const input = [{ foo: 1, bar: 2}, {foo: 3, bar: 4}]
```

and you want:

```
{ foo: [1, 3], bar: [2, 4] }
```

In other words, you want to take an array of things (objects in this case), and *reduce* it down to a single value (an object containing arrays of the other objects' values).  As it turns out, Javascript has a method for doing exactly that, and I used that specific verb for a reason ...

```
const output = input.reduce((objectWithMergedProperties, currentObject) => {
  objectWithMergedProperties.foo.push(currentObject.foo);
  objectWithMergedProperties.bar.push(currentObject.bar);

  return objectWithMergedProperties;
}, { foo: [], bar: [] });
```

This works because `reduce` iterates through your array, starting with an initial `objectWithMergedProperties` of `{ foo: [], bar: [] }` ... but then with each iteration it changes it to whatever gets returned inside the callback.

This lets you add the values of each iteration's object to the output object you want to build, and then return that object from inside the callback.  After all the iterating is done that object will finally be returned from the entire `reduce` call.

Of course, your example wasn't with objects that have `foo` and `bar` properties, but hopefully this demonstrates how you can use `reduce` to reduce *any* array with *any* values into a single object.

And of course if you had a lot of properties you could always do some more iteration (through your object's keys) instead of hard-coding them:

```
  objectWithMergedProperties.foo.push(currentObject.foo);
  objectWithMergedProperties.bar.push(currentObject.bar);
```

could become:

```
  Object.keys(objectWithMergedProperties)
    .forEach(key => objectWithMergedProperties[key].push(currentObject[key]);
```

Comment: Testing this now =D

Comment: Hmm this gave me the same problem as the other answer, the arrays inside the objects are not merging.

Comment: Got it solved, but I greatly appreciate your time none the less and I learned something from this code you supplied so thanks!